# How do I rename a column in a database table using SQL?

Tags: sql, database, rename

If I wish to simply rename a column (not change its type or constraints, just its name) in an SQL database using SQL, how do I do that?  Or is it not possible?

This is for any database claiming to support SQL, I'm simply looking for an SQL-specific query that will work regardless of actual database implementation.

Comment: Seconding skaffman, this is not a "SQL" question, it is (maybe) a "SQLServer" question.

Comment: Any database system that purports to use SQL.  Oracle, MySQL, etc...I'm looking for a database-independent answer.

Answer (score 113, accepted):

On PostgreSQL (and many other RDBMS), you can do it with regular `ALTER TABLE` statement:

```
=> SELECT * FROM Test1;
 id | foo | bar 
----+-----+-----
  2 |   1 |   2

=> ALTER TABLE Test1 RENAME COLUMN foo TO baz;
ALTER TABLE

=> SELECT * FROM Test1;
 id | baz | bar 
----+-----+-----
  2 |   1 |   2
```

Comment: This is not supported in MySQL, is it?

Comment: No,its not supported in MySQL

Comment: This is also not supported in Microsoft SQL Server. Instead use `sp_rename` as per Galwegian's answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/174586/834431

Comment: I believe MySQL 8.0 supports this syntax now

Answer (score 149):

Specifically for SQL Server, use [`sp_rename`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188351.aspx)

```
USE AdventureWorks;
GO
EXEC sp_rename 'Sales.SalesTerritory.TerritoryID', 'TerrID', 'COLUMN';
GO
```

Comment: It seems Microsoft-specific and nothing in the original query indicated a Microsoft DBMS.

Comment: Yes, the answer I was looking for is "standard" SQL, and not dependent on any particular implementation.  However, it is a good answer for anyone using Microsoft's system.

Comment: Note to all: don't use something like `EXEC sp_rename '[Sales].[SalesTerritory].[TerritoryID]', '[TerrID]', 'COLUMN';`, as it will literally rename the column to `[TerrID]`, which will break a lot of stuff... talking from experience here...

Comment: [Yes], [I'm] [not] [sure] [why] [the] [proverbial] [Bill] [Gates] [chose] [to] [use] [square] [brackets] [around] [identifier] [names]. [It's] [really] [dumb]!

Comment: @ReversedEngineer _aesthetic_

Answer (score 41):

In MySQL, the syntax is [`ALTER TABLE ... CHANGE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/alter-table.html):

```
ALTER TABLE <table_name> CHANGE <column_name> <new_column_name> <data_type> ...
```

Note that you can't just rename and leave the type and constraints as is; you must retype the data type and constraints after the new name of the column.

Comment: it is tested in mySQL database

Comment: We can just rename column without affecting type/constraint with `RENAME` syntax. [Rename a column in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30290880/rename-a-column-in-mysql/49925232#49925232)

Answer (score 30):

Unfortunately, for a database independent solution, you will need to know everything about the column. If it is used in other tables as a foreign key, they will need to be modified as well.

```
ALTER TABLE MyTable ADD MyNewColumn OLD_COLUMN_TYPE;
UPDATE MyTable SET MyNewColumn = MyOldColumn;
-- add all necessary triggers and constraints to the new column...
-- update all foreign key usages to point to the new column...
ALTER TABLE MyTable DROP COLUMN MyOldColumn;
```

For the very simplest of cases (no constraints, triggers, indexes or keys), it will take the above 3 lines. For anything more complicated it can get very messy as you fill in the missing parts.

However, as mentioned above, there are simpler database specific methods if you know which database you need to modify ahead of time.

Comment: Directly answers the question, even if it's not exactly what the asker was looking for...

Comment: In the comment, OP actually clarified that this is exactly what he was looking for.

Answer (score 25):

I think this is the easiest way to change column name.

```
SP_RENAME 'TABLE_NAME.OLD_COLUMN_NAME','NEW_COLUMN_NAME'
```

Comment: this worked for me on SQL Server. I am not sure if this works on other DBMS

Comment: Worked on SqlServer , Thanks

Answer (score 12):

In sql server you can use

```
exec sp_rename '<TableName.OldColumnName>','<NewColumnName>','COLUMN'
```

or

```
sp_rename '<TableName.OldColumnName>','<NewColumnName>','COLUMN'
```

Answer (score 9):

In Informix, you can use:

```
RENAME COLUMN TableName.OldName TO NewName;
```

This was implemented before the SQL standard addressed the issue - if it is addressed in the SQL standard.  My copy of the SQL 9075:2003 standard does not show it as being standard (amongst other things, RENAME is not one of the keywords).  I don't know whether it is actually in SQL 9075:2008.

Comment: No RENAME in SQL 2008 Draft too.

Comment: Not AS - use TO.


`RENAME COLUMN TableName.OldName TO NewName;`

http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSGU8G_11.50.0/com.ibm.sqls.doc/ids_sqs_0939.htm

Answer (score 6):

You can use the following command to rename the column of any table in SQL Server:

```
exec sp_rename 'TableName.OldColumnName', 'New colunmName'
```

Answer (score 3):

ALTER TABLE is standard SQL.  But it's not completely implemented in many database systems.

Comment: I accepted bortz' answer over yours because he gave a detailed explanation.  Nevertheless, I upvoted you.

Comment: @MetroidFan2002 - I only added my answer to acknowledge that "ALTER TABLE" isn't just PostgreSQL, it's pretty common.

Answer (score 2):

The standard would be `ALTER TABLE`, but that's not necessarily supported by every DBMS you're likely to encounter, so if you're looking for an all-encompassing syntax, you may be out of luck.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively to `SQL`, you can do this in Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio, from the table Design Panel.

First Way

Slow double-click on the column. The column name will become an editable text box.

Second Way

> SqlManagement Studio>>DataBases>>tables>>specificTable>>Column
>   Folder>>Right Click on column>>Reman

Third Way

Table>>RightClick>>Design

Answer (score 0):

**To rename you have to change the column**

e.g

Suppose

*registration is Table Name

newRefereeName is a column name That I want to change to refereeName
SO my SQL Query will be*

**ALTER TABLE 'registration' CHANGE 'newRefereeName' 'refereeName' VARCHAR(100) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_general_ci NOT NULL;**