# SQLite how to delete all connected rows from other tables?

Tags: sqlite

i have the following problem. I have three tables, TABLE_1, TABLE_2 and TABLE_3.

Between TABLE_1 and TABLE_2 is a m:n relationship so theres a connecting table
lets call it TABLE_1_2.

Between TABLE_2 and TABLE_3 is a m:n relationship so theres a connecting table
lets call it TABLE_2_3.

If i delete now a row from TABLE_1 i want that all rows from the other tables connecte also will be deleted.
How can i handle this? i read that sqlite doesnt supports joins for delete statements.

Comment: You're probably looking to setup foreign keys http://www.sqlite.org/foreignkeys.html =) From this you can setup cascade deletes on the FK relations.

Answer (score 0):

In MS SQL this can be made via altering the table1 and corresponding column by adding ON DELETE CASCADE CONSTRAINT on this column. But in SQLite there is no ALTER COLUMN and ALTER TABLE is also much less functional than in MS SQL. That's why you'll probably have to

- Rename the table1 to a table3
- Create a new table with ON DELETE CASCADE CONSTRAINT and all other constraints you've already used.
- Copy the content of the old table to the new one.
- Remove the old table

See also the [similar topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4007014/alter-column-in-sqlit).

Comment: OK, but im not sure if i understood this correctly. in my connecting tables i already have foreign-keys with on delete cascade. so do i need it in my TABLE_1 also? does it matter which column the on delete cascade has?

Comment: Yes, as deleting happens in table_1. It must cause if the CONSTRAINT ON DELETE CASCADE is enabled deleting in your connecting table TABLE_1_2 and if you have there ON DELETE CASCADE too, it will cause deleting in TABLE_2.

Comment: but that doesnt happens! if i delete something on TABLE_1 just the entry from TABLE_1 and from TABLE_1_2 is deleted. not the entry in TABLE_2.....

Comment: But does TABLE_1_2 have ON DELETE CASCADE too?