# sqlite3 update/adding data to new column

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite

I made new column with *NULL* values called 'id' in table. Now I want to add data to it from list. It holds about 130k elements.

I tried with insert, it returned error:

```
conn = create_connection(xml_db)
cursor = conn.cursor()
with conn:
    cursor.execute("ALTER TABLE xml_table ADD COLUMN id integer")
    for data in ssetId:
        cursor.execute("INSERT INTO xml_table(id) VALUES (?)", (data,))
        conn.commit()
```

I also tried with update:

```
conn = create_connection(xml_db)
cursor = conn.cursor()
with conn:
    cursor.execute("ALTER TABLE xml_table ADD COLUMN id INTEGER")
    for data in ssetId:
        cursor.execute("UPDATE xml_table SET ('id' = ?)", (data,))
        conn.commit()
```

What is incorrect here ?

**EDIT** for clarification.

The table was already existing, filled with data. I want to add column 'id' with custom  values to it.

Comment: I'm confused why you have to alter the table after its been created. Is there some reason you can't create the table with the column to begin with? Something like `create table if not exists xml_table (id INTEGER);`

Comment: If you want to update a specific row, you have to have a WHERE clause in the UPDATE to limit it to just one... otherwise it'll update every single row with the new value.

Comment: @SeanBreckenridge The table was already made and holds values with columns. I want to add new column and fill it with data from list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Heres an example similar to yours which may be useful.

```
import sqlite3

conn = sqlite3.connect("xml.db")

cursor = conn.cursor()

with conn:

    # for testing purposes, remove this or else the table gets dropped whenever the file is loaded
    cursor.execute("drop table if exists xml_table")

    # create table with some other field
    cursor.execute("create table if not exists xml_table (other_field integer not null)")

    for other_data in range(5):
        cursor.execute("INSERT INTO xml_table (other_field) VALUES (?)", (other_data,))

    # add id field
    cursor.execute("ALTER TABLE xml_table ADD COLUMN id integer")

    # make sure the table exists
    res = cursor.execute("SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table'")
    print("Table Name: {}".format(res.fetchone()[0]))

    # add data to the table
    for data in range(5):
        cursor.execute("UPDATE xml_table SET id = ? WHERE other_field = ?", (data, data))

    # if you must insert an id, you must specify a other_field value as well, since other_field must be not null
    cursor.execute("insert into xml_table (id, other_field) VALUES (? ,?)", (100, 105))


    # make sure data exists
    res = cursor.execute("SELECT id, other_field FROM xml_table")
    for id_result in res:
        print(id_result)

    conn.commit()

conn.close()
```

As I stated in the comment below, since one of your rows has a `NOT NULL` constraint on it, no rows can exist in the table that have that column `NULL`. In the example above `other_field` is specified `NOT NULL`, therefore there can be no rows that have `NULL` values in the column `other_field`. Any deviation from this would be an `IntegrityError`.

Output:

```
Table Name: xml_table
(0, 0)
(1, 1)
(2, 2)
(3, 3)
(4, 4)
(100, 105)
```

Comment: Edited OP for clarification - Table is already filled with data and columns. I want to add new column and fill its values from list.

Comment: @flowian Edited. I'm confused why this is an issue, it doesn't feel right to add to a table in the middle of execution. In any case, What is the error you're getting?

Comment: `IntegrityError: NOT NULL constraint failed: xml_table.column_1`

The error is about:

`cursor.execute("INSERT INTO xml_table(id) VALUES (?)", (data,))`

Comment: **it doesn't feel right to add to a table in the middle of execution.**


You mean that `conn.commit()` should be out of `for` cycle ?

Comment: No, just in general. If you need to add a column for something, why doesnt it exist in the first place. The `IntegrityError` states that you tried to insert some `id` value into `xml_table`, but there was another column that has a `not null` constraint on it, and you're not respecting that. In other words, there can be no rows in the table that have `xml_table.column_1` null, and many of the inserts attempted in `INSERT INTO xml_table(id) VALUES (?)` pay no regard to `column1`. I shall update my answer to reflect this constraint.

Comment: I see. Is it possible fill new column while keeping other columns untouched though?

Comment: Theres [no way to alter a column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4007014/]) after creating it in sqlite. If possible, and if it makes sense for your data, you could remove the not null constraint from `column1` (which would be located at its definition/creation), but Im unsure of what that means for your data. Currently, the `NOT NULL` constraint essentially means "Any row that gets inserted must have this column". You could insert it with a dummy value for `column1`, but then you're breaking the error checking thats built into the table.