# What to do to make an existing non-optional field optional in database table in SQlite?

Tags: ios, grdb

I am using `GRDB` for local persistence.

Created a column in the `Item` table with the following constraints.

`table.column(Item.CodingKeys.text.rawValue, .text).notNull()`

Now I want to change it to support optional values as well.

`table.column(Item.CodingKeys.text.rawValue, .text)`

But in order to migrate, I cant alter its property. Only `add, rename` available for the column.

What approach should I take to properly migrate while keeping backward compatibility?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ALTER COLUMN` is not possible in `SQLite`.

Only Supported alter operations:

- Alter Table Name
- Alter Table Column Name
- Add New Column
- Drop Column

Reference:

- [Sqlite Alter Table](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_altertable.html)
- [Alter column in sqlite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4007014/alter-column-in-sqlite)

Comment: This shared [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68555703/what-to-do-to-make-an-existing-non-optional-field-optional-in-database-table-in) answered it.