# How do I correct a wrong Room migration?

Tags: android, sqlite, android-room

I added a column to a table, then added the following migration (version 56 to 57):

```
private val MIGRATION_56_57 = object : Migration(56, 57) {
    override fun migrate(database: SupportSQLiteDatabase) {
        database.execSQL("ALTER TABLE `app_stage` ADD COLUMN hasSeenBusinessOwnerQuestion INTEGER DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL")
    }
}
```

After building and releasing the app to our existing users, they get a migration error and the app crashes. To correct the error, I just need to change:`hasSeenBusinessOwnerQuestion INTEGER DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL`
to:`hasSeenBusinessOwnerQuestion INTEGER DEFAULT 0`  .

Should I just add another migration from version 57 to 58 as:

```
 private val MIGRATION_57_58 = object : Migration(57, 58) {
    override fun migrate(database: SupportSQLiteDatabase) {
        database.execSQL("ALTER TABLE `app_stage` ADD COLUMN hasSeenBusinessOwnerQuestion INTEGER DEFAULT 0 ")
    }
}
```

?
Will existing users upgrading from version 56 all the way to 58 get that same migration error? How do I add another migration to version 58 to avoid migration errors?

Comment: I think you can't alter a column. So if the 56-57 migration added the column, you can't change it by running using another ADD COLUMN. See  https://stackoverflow.com/a/4007086/2649154

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ? Will existing users upgrading from version 56 all the way to 58 get that same migration error?

**No** Room will invoke all the migrations in sequence (56-57 and then 57-58) and then **after all the migrations have been performed** continue with the database build.

**However** you cannot use the ALTER command to ADD an already existing column, which would be the case going from 57-58. So the migration would fail.

Although later versions of SQLite (3.35.0) support  `ALTER TABLE .... DROP COLUMN ....`, this version is not available at present on Android devices and that there is no ALTER COLUMN. You will have to use an alternative means to alter the column.

- The DROP COLUMN is also quite restrictive

You could do the following (where **?** represents the table in question):-

1. `DROP TABLE IF EXISTS ?_old`

   1. this is just in-case it exists (it should not)
2. Use the `ALTER TABLE ? RENAME TO ?_old` (_old just a suggested name for what is to be a temporary version of the table)
3. Use `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ....`

   1. Room demands that the create table SQL creates the table according to how it interprets the class annotated with @Entity.
   2. It is suggested that you retrieve the create table SQL from the generated java that is available after compiling the project. The SQL will be in the **createAllTables** method of the class that is the same as the class that is annotated with @Database but suffixed with **_Impl**
4. Use `INSERT INTO ? SELECT * FROM ?_old` to copy existing data into the newly created version of the table
5. Use `DROP TABLE IF EXISTS ?`

So **apart from the `CREATE TABLE ....`** (which would have to be altered, see points above) the following would cater for all scenarios (new users, users on 57 and users on 56) :-

```
    private val MIGRATION_57_58 = object : Migration(57, 58) {
        override fun migrate(database: SupportSQLiteDatabase) {
            database.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `app_stage_old`")
            database.execSQL("ALTER TABLE `app_stage` RENAME TO `app_stage_old`")
            /* NOTE the CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS .... SHOULD BE ALTERED ACCORDINGLY */
            database.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `app_stage` (`id` INTEGER, `name` TEXT NOT NULL,`hasSeenBusinessOwnerQuestion` INTEGER DEFAULT 0, PRIMARY KEY(`id`))")
            database.execSQL("INSERT INTO `app_stage` SELECT * FROM `app_stage_old`")
            database.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `app_stage_old`")
        }
    }
```