# Can't rename field database with my query

Tags: android, sqlite

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I rename a column in a SQLite database table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/805363/how-do-i-rename-a-column-in-a-sqlite-database-table)

I want to rename field table in SQlite, but I can't rename it in my aplication. This my query to rename:

```
ALTER TABLE 'table_name' RENAME 'column1' TO 'new_column1'
```

but my query gets this error:

```
SQLiteManager: Likely SQL syntax error: ALTER table 'table_name' 
RENAME 'column1' TO 'new_column1' [ near "'column1'": syntax error ]

Exception Name: NS_ERROR_FAILURE
Exception Message: Component returned failure code: 0x80004005 
(NS_ERROR_FAILURE) [mozIStorageConnection.createStatement]
```

and can't rename field...
i change my query :

```
ALTER TABLE 'table_name' RENAME COLUMN 'column1' TO 'new_column1'
ALTER TABLE 'table_name' CHANGE 'column1' 'new_column1' TEXT
```

and error again...
how do I solve my problem??

Comment: exact duplicate of "How do I rename a column in a SQLite database table?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't directly rename a column in a SQLite table. You need to re-create the table. The overall process is this

1.- create a new table with the new column

2.- copy all the old table contents to the new table

3.- recreate all indexes

4.- rename the old table to another name

5.- rename the new table to the original name

Comment: ok .. but i have to calculate the length of time to do that when the table contains 1000 row...and thanks for the suggestion....