# How to Apply a SQLite Command to All Tables

Tags: sqlite

Say that I want to run the following SQLite command to delete all rows in a particular table where the Name column is NULL:

```
DELETE FROM myTable WHERE Name IS NULL;
```

Now let's say that I've got 20 tables, and they aren't named in any pattern. I want to delete all rows where the Name column is NULL from every table in the database. Is there a statement I can use to do this in one go? Or will I have to run one statement to get the table names, then take the output and run 20 or so commands using each table name?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's my first crack at it from the sqlite3 console :

```
.output tmp

SELECT "DELETE FROM " || sqlite_master.name || 
" WHERE name is NULL;" FROM sqlite_master 
WHERE type = "table" AND sqlite_master.name NOT LIKE 'sqlite_%';

.read tmp
```

This generates the delete statements for each table, outputs it to a file and then reads and runs that file.

(My comment was about the syntax in another answer, you can only delete from one table per delete statement.)

Comment: Is the name variable in between the concatenations the same as the name variable in the `"where name is null"` statement?

Comment: " where name is null " represents the name field in your tables.   In the other two places it is the name of the table from the sqlite_master table.

Comment: Very useful sqlite commands, also to RENAME a column in all tables with spaced long names using **triple quotes:**
SELECT "ALTER TABLE """|| sqlite_master.name ||""" RENAME COLUMN old_name TO new_name;" FROM sqlite_master 
WHERE type = "table" AND sqlite_master.name NOT LIKE 'sqlite_%';

Answer (score 0):

If you have mandatory column 'Name' in every table, then

```
  DELETE FROM myTable1, myTable2, myTable3 WHERE Name IS NULL;
```

Comment: The tables aren't named in any particular pattern, so I couldn't do `myTable1, myTable2, myTable3` and I might not be able to hardcode the names in anyway. Let's say they have the same column names though for simplicity.

Comment: This is not valid SQLite,  you can only delete from one table at a time.