# How to delete the multiple columns from the SQL table in SQlite3?

Tags: c, database, sqlite

My database contains 'n' number of columns:

```
  name   Phone_no  Person_1    Person_2      Person_3     Person_4
  john     123        1           2            3            4
  Nolan   1234        23          34           1            5
```

- If the Phone_no is 1234  then I want to delete the columns Person_1, Person_3.
- I know about the column numbers(Column 3( Person_1), Column 5( Person_3 ))  which has to be deleted.
- Is there any way to delete the multiple columns through a single SQL statement.

Comment: Delete column or set null to those column values?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Delete column from SQLite table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5938048/delete-column-from-sqlite-table)

Comment: @kuro Delete column

Comment: @VikasVijayan, If you delete the column then it will be deleted for all rows. Do you want that?

Comment: @kuro yes. I want to remove the column itself from my table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
update mytable set person_1 = null, person_5 = null
where phone_no = 1234
```

I understand that by *delete columns `person_1` and `person_3` where `phone_no` is 1234* you mean *set values to null in columns `person_1` and `person_3` where `phone_no` is 1234*.

If you want to actually remove the columns, then it's a different question. In SQLite, you need to recreate the table:

```
create table tmp_table(
    name varchar(50),         -- adapt the datatypes and lengths to your requirement
    phone_no int,
    person_2 varchar(50),
    person_4 varchar(50)
);
insert into tmp select name, phone, person_2, person_4 from mytable;
drop table mytable;

create table mytable(
    name varchar(50),
    phone_no int,
    person_2 varchar(50),
    person_4 varchar(50)
);
insert into mytable select name, phone, person_2, person_4 from tmp_table;
drop table tmp_table;
```

Comment: I want to delete the columns. If I set it to NULL it will be displayed in the database.

Comment: @VikasVijayan: do you want to *drop* (remove) the column? If you do that, the column will not exist in the table anymore (regardless of the value of `phone_no`), is this what you want?

Comment: Yes. I want to drop the column. I don't need those columns in the table.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any way to delete the multiple columns through a single SQL statement.

Another way is to run a single SQLite3 statement multiple times:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/16162224/3426192

e.g: SQLite 2021-03-12 (3.35.0) now supports: `DROP COLUMN`