# How to remove auto increment of table column in sqlite?

Tags: iphone, ios, database, sqlite

i had create my table using below code:

```
create table tbl_questionnair(qid integer primary key autoincrement, title varchar, uid integer, superadminid integer,TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);
```

Now i want to remove auto increment of qid. Anyone can help me?

Answer (score 1):

sqLite doesnot support alter table so drop the older table and create it once again

Simply remove the qid as primary key.

> create table tbl_questionnair(qid integer, title varchar, uid integer, superadminid integer,TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);

Comment: Yes, and one can use a relatively concise sequence of statements to create a new table, copy from old to new, and delete the old.  See http://stackoverflow.com/a/805508/581994