# Using alias for SQLiteDatabase JOIN queries

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

My issue is simple. I'm doing a JOIN `rawQuery()` to get columns `User._id` and `Teacher._id` and the tables `from users AS User join teachers AS Teacher`

The cursor seems not to care about the alias so it overrides `User._id` value with `Teacher._id`  cause both columns are just `_id` for the `Cursor`

How can I solve this?  i need all that data in 1 cursor so having 2 cursors isn't an option

**Edit:** I want to avoid changing or renaming the column `_id` because of the design patters, isn't there a way to use alias for tables as in `MySQL`?

**Edit 2:** or maybe changing the column name but only inside the `Cursor`, not the actual column name

Comment: You are renaming the **tables**, not the **columns**...

Comment: what do you get if you print the column names in the cursor ? (you probably can infer the column indexes from the query, and use that instead of getColumnIndex(), too)

Comment: as @Vyger suggests, you can create aliases for your columns, rather that for your tables. `select User._id as userid, Teacher._id as teacherid ...`

Answer (score 0):

I think the solution is very simple. First rename one of the columns, and then try to JOIN them. I think this will be useful for you:
[rename column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/805363/how-do-i-rename-a-column-in-a-sqlite-database-table)

Comment: @njzk: +1 for the sense of humor!

Comment: first: it's your choice to choose a good name for the new column. Second: the new name will be on a new copy of the table and you won't affect the original table.

Comment: @Conducted : yes, and `_id` is a very good name for an id column, no matter which table it is.

Comment: I mean, do not drop the original table. Drop the newly created table after you done.

Comment: @njzk2: you must be so tired that you have no more id... ;)