# RSQLite, how to add column names to tables?

Tags: r, sqlite, rsqlite

I have dumped several .txt files to an SQLite database on my computer's hard disk using RSQLite package. Since the .txt files have no headers, I have to use the "header = FALSE" argument. Here is how my codes look:

```
for (i in (1:8)) {
dbWriteTable(conn = db, name = tbls[i], value = paths[i], 
             row.names = FALSE, header = FALSE, sep = "\t", 
             overwrite = TRUE)
}
```

Now I want to add column names to the tables in the SQLite database, how can I do that?

Comment: I'd suggest setting the column names before writing the table to SQLite, i.e. while the data is in the data.frame: `colnames(df) <- c('col1', 'col2')`.

Comment: Thanks. However the data I dumped to SQLite database is pretty big which is about 10g in size. I just don't think it is efficient to load the data in R first and create column names. Is there any way to directly edit tables in SQLite using RSQLite functions?

Comment: Ok, I see. Have a look at here then: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/805363/how-do-i-rename-a-column-in-a-sqlite-database-table