# SQLite alter column to remove constraint

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I have a column with a NOT NULL constraint. I need to alter the database to remove the constraint. But when I try I get a duplicate column exception from android

```
db.execSQL("ALTER TABLE " + AnimalContract.DogEntry.TABLE_NAME
+ " ADD COLUMN " + AnimalContract.DogEntry.COLUMN_NAME+" TEXT DEFAULT NULL");
```

I also tried without DEFAULT

The constraint was `UNIQUE NOT NULL`

Answer (score 4):

There's no direct way to **ALTER COLUMN** in SQLite.

I believe your only option is to:

- Rename the table to a temporary name
- Create a new table without the NOT NULL constraint
- Copy the content of the old table to the new one
- Remove the old table

[This other Stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/805363/how-do-i-rename-a-column-in-a-sqlite-database-table#805508) explains the process in details

Furthermore,

**MODIFY COLUMN IN TABLE**

You can not use the ALTER TABLE statement to modify a column in SQLite. Instead you will need to rename the table, create a new table, and copy the data into the new table.

**Syntax**

> The syntax to MODIFY A COLUMN in a table in SQLite is:

```
PRAGMA foreign_keys=off;

BEGIN TRANSACTION;

ALTER TABLE table1 RENAME TO _table1_old;

CREATE TABLE table1 (
( column1 datatype [ NULL | NOT NULL ],
  column2 datatype [ NULL | NOT NULL ],
  ...
);

INSERT INTO table1 (column1, column2)
 SELECT column1, column2
  FROM _table1_old;

COMMIT;

PRAGMA foreign_keys=on;
```

> Example
>
> Let's look at an example that shows how to modify a column in a SQLite table.
>
> For example, if we had an employees table that had a column called last_name that was defined as a CHAR datatype:

```
CREATE TABLE employees
( employee_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
  last_name CHAR NOT NULL,
  first_name VARCHAR,
  hire_date DATE
);
```

> And we wanted to change the datatype of the last_name field to VARCHAR, we could do the following:

```
PRAGMA foreign_keys=off;

BEGIN TRANSACTION;

ALTER TABLE employees RENAME TO _employees_old;

CREATE TABLE employees
( employee_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
  last_name VARCHAR NOT NULL,
  first_name VARCHAR,
  hire_date DATE
);

INSERT INTO employees (employee_id, last_name, first_name, hire_date)
  SELECT employee_id, last_name, first_name, hire_date
  FROM _employees_old;

COMMIT;

PRAGMA foreign_keys=on;
```

> This example will rename our existing employees table to _employees_old.
>   Then it will create the new employees table with the last_name field defined as a VARCHAR datatype. Then it will insert all of the data from the _employees_old table into the employees table.