# renaming a column in a SQLiteDatabase query

Tags: android, sqlite

I currently have the query which selects the corresponding row with the given `id`

```
Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_MEMOS, new String[] { KEY_ID, KEY_TITLE,
                         KEY_BODY, KEY_IMPOR, KEY_ALERT }, KEY_ID + "=?",
                         new String[] { String.valueOf(id) }, null, null, null, null);
```

I need to cast the column `KEY_ID` name to `_id` for it to work with cursors but can't figure out where to add the `AS` command into the query.

Comment: can you please checkout this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/805363/how-do-i-rename-a-column-in-a-sqlite-database-table[enter link description here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/805363/how-do-i-rename-a-column-in-a-sqlite-database-table)

Answer (score 1):

You can specify column aliases in the string array containing column names, e.g.

```
String[] cols = new String { KEY_ID + "AS _id", KEY_TITLE,
                             KEY_BODY, KEY_IMPOR, KEY_ALERT };
```

Comment: Perfect that's worked thanks! I also feel silly for not spotting something so easy.

Comment: I shall do, need to wait 3 mins before i can accept.