# Android Room: How to Migrate Column Renaming?

Tags: android, sql, android-sqlite, android-room

## Issue

My app is crashing because I am not handling migration properly. **I'm looking for a solution to migrate the name of 1 column in my table.**

In my project I a have a room table named '*content*' with a **Double** attribute '*archivedCount*'. In the latest version of the app the attribute *archivedCount* attribute is re-named to *dismissCount*, still as type **Double.**

**Original Content model**

```
@Entity(tableName = "content")
data class Content(@PrimaryKey var id: String, var archiveCount: Double) : Parcelable {...}
```

**New Content model**

```
@Entity(tableName = "content")
data class Content(@PrimaryKey var id: String, var dismissCount: Double) : Parcelable {...}
```

## Attempted Solution

After reading a Google Developer Advocate's explanation [Understanding migrations with Room](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/understanding-migrations-with-room-f01e04b07929), I attempted her solution outlined in the post's section **Migrations with complex schema changes** which entails making a copy of the original table, deleting the old table, then renaming the newly created table.

With the following approach below there is a runtime error on this line: `database.execSQL("INSERT INTO content_new (id, dismissCount) SELECT id, archiveCount FROM users");` because I already cleared my app's cache so the old table no longer exists.

**Can I update a single column without re-creating the entire table?**

```
static final Migration MIGRATION_1_2 = new Migration(1, 2) {
@Override
public void migrate(SupportSQLiteDatabase database) {
    // Create the new table
    database.execSQL(
            "CREATE TABLE content_new (id TEXT, dismissCount REAL, PRIMARY KEY(id))");
    // Copy the data
    database.execSQL("INSERT INTO content_new (id, dismissCount) SELECT id, archiveCount FROM users");
    // Remove the old table
    database.execSQL("DROP TABLE content");
    // Change the table name to the correct one
    database.execSQL("ALTER TABLE content_new RENAME TO content");
  }
};
```

Comment: Have you read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/805363/how-do-i-rename-a-column-in-a-sqlite-database-table)?

Comment: Thank you @TimBiegeleisen. How would I format the SQL command as the post doesn't provide an example. I'm trying this, but the IDE does not like the syntax: `database.execSQL("ALTER TABLE 'content' RENAME COLUMN 'archiveCount' TO 'dismissCount'")`. Is it possible my syntax is correct,  and IntelliJ just has not updated to this new rule?

Comment: It turns out my syntax in the comment above causes a crash. How would I format this new SQL action? `android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "COLUMN": syntax error (code 1 SQLITE_ERROR): , while compiling: ALTER TABLE 'content' RENAME COLUMN 'archiveCount' TO 'dismissCount'`

Comment: Stop putting single quotes around your table and column names.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I removed the quotes within the command `database.execSQL("ALTER TABLE content RENAME COLUMN archiveCount TO dismissCount")`. IntelliJ still does not like the syntax.

Comment: What does IntelliJ have to do with this?  What _SQLite_ errors are you still getting?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen IntelliJ is showing a warning that it is not a valid SQL command. **COLUM** is higlighted in red and it says *TO expected, got 'COLUMN'* This is the specific error I'm receiving in runtime which causes the crash: `android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "COLUMN": syntax error (code 1 SQLITE_ERROR): , while compiling: ALTER TABLE content RENAME COLUMN archiveCount TO dismissCount`

Comment: What version of SQLite are you using?

Comment: The API I'm on uses **3.19**. From your link it looks like I'll have to wait until they update to **3.25**.

Comment: Yeah...that's what I was going to say.  You may have to drop and recreate the table in your case.  By the way, for future reference for a question like this, please tell us your SQLite version in the question.

Comment: Will do! May you upvote as this is going to be a common issue for developers on Android once Room is adopted more widely.

Comment: I know this is an older question, but as of November 2020, this is still 100% not doable with the current room db logic. You cannot rename a column since the SQLite version is not up to 3.25 and until that point you need to create a new table, copy the table data, drop the old table, and rename the new table. It's extremely tedious, but it's the only working way that isn't a hack like renaming the serialized vars.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I rename a column in a SQLite database table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/805363/how-do-i-rename-a-column-in-a-sqlite-database-table)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

## Solution

Thanks to the guidance from @TimBiegeleisen we discovered that the [Android implementation of SQLite](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/package-summary) **3.19** for **API 27** and **28** has not yet upgraded to the version **3.25** SQLite which allows this feature outlined in this [StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/805363/how-do-i-rename-a-column-in-a-sqlite-database-table).

Once Android upgrades a command such as this to alter a table column will be possible: `database.execSQL("ALTER TABLE content RENAME COLUMN archiveCount TO dismissCount")`

Comment: Is it still not there in SQLite?

I have written this: 
database.execSQL("ALTER TABLE Expense RENAME COLUMN price TO amount");

Getting an error 
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "COLUMN": syntax error (code 1 SQLITE_ERROR): , while compiling: ALTER TABLE Expense RENAME COLUMN price TO amount

And also I get hint at that line: got COLUMN, expected TO

Comment: It really needs to be noted that this does not work on Android devices that are not using SQLite 3.25, which at the time of this comment is **ALL** of them, so this answer is not correct as of 2020-11-11. The only solution I have found is to use the logic to create a new table, copy over the data, drop the old table, and rename the new table.

Answer (score 14):

There is a solution without migration - use [ColumnInfo](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/persistence/room/ColumnInfo):

```
data class Content(@PrimaryKey var id: String,  @ColumnInfo(name = "archiveCount") var dismissCount: Double) : Parcelable{...}
```

Database column will be still `archiveCount`, but in Kotlin property will be renamed.

Comment: Thanks @atarasenki, this is a nice workaround. However, it does not solve the root of the issue and is more of a "band aid" type solution.