# Can't migrate column renaming in room database

Tags: android, database-migration, android-room

I was trying to run migration while renaming a column in room database.
My code is following

```
    public static final Migration MIGRATION_11_12 = new Migration(11, 12) {
        @Override
        public void migrate(SupportSQLiteDatabase database) {
            database.execSQL("ALTER TABLE content RENAME COLUMN archiveCount TO dismissCount");
        }
    };
```

Besides android studio is detecting the following error

[image]

Although, it was compiling without any problem .

And I am getting the following error in the above code , while running migration test

```
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "COLUMN": syntax error (code 1)
```

Comment: The same mentioned in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52657760/android-room-how-to-migrate-column-renaming

Comment: I have seen that , I exactly followed this , but the getting the error mentioned in my question .

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android Room: How to Migrate Column Renaming?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52657760/android-room-how-to-migrate-column-renaming)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I rename a column in a SQLite database table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/805363/how-do-i-rename-a-column-in-a-sqlite-database-table)

Answer (score -2):

```
database.execSQL("ALTER TABLE content RENAME archiveCount TO dismissCount");
```

ALTER TABLE content_new RENAME TO content
Remove `COLUMN` keyword from query.

Here is syntax

```
ALTER TABLE table_name 
RENAME column_name TO new_column_name;
```

Comment: Same problem , android studio is showing same warning and , while building getting same error .