# rename column of sqlite database when upgrade database_version

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-sqlite

how can rename column of table in SQlite database android when upgrade database_version

```
  @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int i, int i1) {
        if (DATABASE_VERSION == 2) {
           ????
        }

        onCreate(db);
    }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android Room: How to Migrate Column Renaming?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52657760/android-room-how-to-migrate-column-renaming)

Comment: @NicolaGallazzi it is obvious that the OP is not using ROOM.

Comment: @forpas, sure thing, my bad! However Room is not the point here, as the SQLite syntax would be the same

Comment: i dont want migrate and rename table or alter or add column .forexample my column name  in last version was a and in new version will be b. i want rename column in onUpgrade method without clear table or clear last version of application

Answer (score 2):

With `ALTER TABLE` you can change the column's name (version of SQLite: **3.25.0+**):

```
if (DATABASE_VERSION == 2) {
    db.execSQL("alter table tablename rename columnname to newcolumnname");
}
```

Comment: thanks for your solution .it means i should renam column dynamically iwith this code?

Comment: Replace `columnname` and `newcolumnname` with the current and the new name of the column.