# Android Room, SQLite - TO expected, got 'COLUMN'

Tags: android, sqlite, android-room

I'm trying to rename a column in my Room database. I foolishly used the column name `index` and want to change it to `id`, but this migration function is causing headaches:

```
static final Migration MIGRATION_2_3 = new Migration(2, 3) {
        @Override
        public void migrate(@NonNull SupportSQLiteDatabase database) {
            database.execSQL("ALTER TABLE items RENAME COLUMN index TO id;");
        }
    };
```

I followed this syntax diagram for the query:

[image: SQLite alter table syntax UML]

Android Studio is giving me the error `TO expected, got 'COLUMN'`, and I cannot use the database due to the RuntimeException:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Room cannot verify the data integrity. Looks like you've changed schema but forgot to update the version number. You can simply fix this by increasing the version number.
```

The version number is correct, so I am assuming this issue is caused by the syntax problem above; I cannot find anything else wrong with my setup.

Comment: Android uses SQLite v3.19. That makes renaming a column using RENAME COLUMN not possible. The best approach is to recreate the table.

Comment: [How do I rename a column in a SQLite database table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/805363/how-do-i-rename-a-column-in-a-sqlite-database-table/52346199#52346199) Probably you are using lower version than 3.25

Comment: @LeoPelozo that is so very annoying. thanks

Comment: `index` must be [quoted](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_keywords.html).

Comment: @CL. yes, I would add some backticks but I'd much rather just have a proper name for the column

Comment: I meant, in the ALTER TABLE statement. (You ran into another error before that.)

Answer (score 1):

*Android uses SQLite v3.19. That makes renaming a column using RENAME COLUMN not possible. The best approach is to recreate the table.* – Leo Pelozo

Looks like I need to create function that drops the table so I can create a new one.

```
@Query("DELETE FROM items")
void dropTable();
```

... then create the table again, though I'm not sure how to go about this.

**Update:**

I was able (I think, we'll see...) to re-create the table by calling the above function, removing ALL migrations and setting the database version back to 1. Then I re-defined the database class itself with the proper names etc. and was able to insert data into it without any errors. Adding `.fallbackToDestructiveMigration()` to my database singleton class was also necessary.

Personally I think this is a little ridiculous just for simply re-naming a column; I was never able to simply rename the column and add a migration for the change, nor was I able to drop the table and re-create it with the proper column name and add that as a migration. But alas, this is Android after all.