# Renaming sqlite3 table column

Tags: python, sqlite

I am struggling to rename my sqlite3 column, with python.

```
if n[:1] == 'B': 
     c.execute('''ALTER TABLE '''+n+''' RENAME COLUMN DRcode TO CRcodetemp''')
```

Where `n = ‘B1’` and `type(n)` is `<class 'str'>` and `c = conn.cursor()`

Error:

```
c.execute('''ALTER TABLE '''+n+''' RENAME COLUMN DRcode TO CRcodetemp''')                                                              
sqlite3.OperationalError: near "COLUMN": syntax error
```

Thanks

Comment: You could temporarily replace the "c.execute" by a "print" to see what exactly is sent to sqlite (and to show it in the question).

Comment: Renaming a column is possible since version 3.25.0: https://sqlite.org/releaselog/3_25_1.html

Comment: Thanks. How do I check my sqlite3 version. printing sqlite3.version gives 2.6.0 which I believe refers to the python version sqlite is using?

Comment: Execute: `select sqlite_version();`

Answer (score 0):

Based on [other questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/805363/how-do-i-rename-a-column-in-a-sqlite-database-table) which I missed, it seems that the only plausible way of doing this is creating a temp table and then creating a new table with the correct column names.

```
if n[:1] == 'B':  # For Bank Accounts
            # rename table, create new table, and put value in correct place
            c.execute('''ALTER TABLE '''+n+''' RENAME TO temp''')
            c.execute('''CREATE TABLE '''+n+''' (id, CRcodetemp)''')
            c.execute('''INSERT INTO '''+n+'''(id, CRcodetemp)
                         SELECT id, DRcode
                         FROM temp''')
            c.execute('''DROP TABLE temp''')
```

Comment: That's incorrect @Ollie. sqlite allows you to rename a column. Your suggestion is required for removing a column.

Comment: If you read [the documentation](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_altertable.html) you'll see that order of operations is explicitly called out as incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

Works fine here:

```
In [1]: import sqlite3

In [2]: db = sqlite3.connect(':memory:')
Out[2]: <sqlite3.Connection at 0x803bfbab0>

In [3]: db.execute('CREATE TABLE B1(foo TEXT, DRcode INT)')
Out[3]: <sqlite3.Cursor at 0x803b30960>

In [4]: db.execute('ALTER TABLE B1 RENAME COLUMN DRcode TO CRcodetemp')
Out[4]: <sqlite3.Cursor at 0x803b30c00>
```

Version info:

```
In [5]: import sys

In [6]: sys.version
Out[6]: '3.7.7 (default, Mar 19 2020, 19:56:47)'

In [7]: sqlite3.version
Out[7]: '2.6.0'
```

Note that the `sqlite3` module version is *not* the same as the sqlite version. In my case the latter is: `SQLite version 3.31.1`.