# How do I rename a column with SQLite?

Tags: system.data.sqlite

I am using "System.Data.SQLite;". The Dll version is 1.0.103.0.

My sql statement is

`ALTER TABLE main.[Resistors] RENAME [Manufacturer Part Number] to [Manufacturer Part Number 1];`

The error message I get is
"Message=SQL logic error or missing database"

I have also tried

`ALTER TABLE [Resistors] RENAME COLUMN [Manufacturer Part Number] to [Manufacturer Part Number 1];`

Which returned "SQL logic error or missing database
near "COLUMN": syntax error"

and tried

`ALTER TABLE main.[Resistors] RENAME COLUMN [Manufacturer Part Number] to [Manufacturer Part Number 1];`

Which returned "SQL logic error or missing database
near "COLUMN": syntax error

I'm assuming I need to change "main." to something else but I don't know what it should be.  Or I need to update my SQLite.  I'm working on that.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I rename a column in a SQLite database table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/805363/how-do-i-rename-a-column-in-a-sqlite-database-table)

Comment: I tried to add the word "Column" but it didn't seem to help.  I'm not sure what I'm missing.

Comment: It looks like my SQLite dll is a bit older.  Looks like I can download the setup from this site.  Can anyone confirm that this the proper way to set it up or update the dll? https://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/doc/trunk/www/downloads.wiki

Comment: I found out that the SQL commands were correct.  The issue was the reference used in visual studio was not supporting the rename command.  I don't know why why but using this nuget package solved the issue. System.Data.SQLite.1.0.116.0.nupkg

Answer (score 0):

Some of the versions of SQLite do not support renaming columns.  Try updating the references available in your project.  See this NuGet Filename.  This version supports renaming columns.

System.Data.SQLite.1.0.116.0.nupkg