# Change column datatype in SELECT in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to change my column value in `categoriID` from numbers to text.

Is this possible?

```
SELECT name, CAST(categoriID AS char(10)) 
FROM customer
WHERE categoriID = 1 AS 'new_text'
```

Here is a link of a pic how i want it: https://i.stack.imgur.com/NVdXR.png

Comment: I want to change the data in CategoriID to a new text, CategoriID is a integer

Comment: The AS in WHERE dosent work

Comment: @roYal: Do you want to get ``new_text`` when `categoriID = 1` ? And do you want to get ``new_text_2`` when `categoriID = 2` and so on ?

Comment: yes but not in the column. I want to change the data in the row

Comment: You want to somehow change also the *value* of the data? It is already a text value after casting to `CHAR(10)`.

Comment: Yes. I'm not sure if the convert works but i dosen't give me an error

Comment: Yes what? You want to change the *value* of the data from, e.g. **1** into **one**, ... something else ... what?

Comment: Yes i want to change the value of the data to an text instead of 1 as it shows in the pic

Comment: But **1** is displayed as **1** in the pic you have attached.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Simplest solution would be a simple join thus:

```
SELECT  c.name, c.categoryID, category.name AS category_name
FROM    customer c
INNER JOIN -- or LEFT JOIN if categoryID allows NULLs
(
SELECT 1, 'First category' UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'Second category' UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 'Third category'
) category(categoryID, name) ON c.categoryID = category.categoryID
```

I would use this solution if list of categories is small, static and if it is needed only for this query.

2) Otherwise, I would create a new table thus

```
CREATE TABLE category -- or dbo.cateogory (note: you should use object's/table's schema)
(
    categoryID INT NOT NULL,
        CONSTRAINT PK_category_categoryID PRIMARY KEY(categoryID),
    name NVARCHAR(50) NOT NULL -- you should use the propper type (varchar maybe) and max length (100 maybe)
    --,      CONSTRAINT IUN_category_name UNIQUE(name) -- uncomment this line if you want to have unique categories (nu duplicate values in column [name])
);
GO
```

plus I would create a foreign key in order to be sure that categories from [customer] table exist also in [category] table:

```
ALTER TABLE customer 
ADD CONSTRAINT FK_customer_categoryID 
FOREIGN KEY (categoryID) REFERENCES category(categoryID)
GO

INSERT category (categoryID, name)
SELECT 1, 'First category' UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'Second category' UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 'Third category'
GO
```

and your query will be

```
SELECT  c.name, c.categoryID, ctg.name AS category_name
FROM    customer c
INNER JOIN ctg ON c.categoryID = ctg.categoryID -- or LEFT JOIN if c.categoryID allows NULLs
```

I would use solution #2.

Answer (score 1):

From [this possible duplicate SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16296622/rename-column-sql-server-2008) on SQL Server 2008:

```
EXEC sp_RENAME table_name , old_name, new_name
```

Or you could do [this](http://www.techonthenet.com/sql/tables/alter_table.php):

```
ALTER TABLE table_name RENAME COLUMN old_name to new_name;
```

**EDIT:** Just got the question. To change the datatype of the column to a text datatype, you could execute this:

```
ALTER TABLE table_name MODIFY column_name CHARACTER(n);
```

where `n` is the number of characters in the string, or:

```
ALTER TABLE table_name MODIFY column_name VARCHAR(n)
```

where `n` is the maximum number of characters in the string.

Note that these will edit the original table. If you just want to select the column as a particular datatype, you'll need to copy the table using:

```
SELECT column_name(s) INTO newtable [IN externaldb] FROM table1;
```

Then, you can modify the column datatype as shown above, and `DROP` the new table if you want to. Another way to do this without a separate table would be to use [`CAST` or `CONVERT`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I'm editing the post to reflect this new understanding of the question.

Answer (score -1):

You can use this Query to change Column datatype,

Syntax:

```
ALTER TABLE table_name ALTER COLUMN column_name datatype;
```

Solution:

```
ALTER TABLE customer ALTER COLUMN categoriID Varchar(50);
```

Answer (score -2):

ALTER TABLE customer CHANGE categoriID categoriID TEXT

Comment: I dont want to change anything in the DB, I only whant to show it as SELECT