# How to sort by varchar field containing a date in ascending order

Tags: sql, sql-server

In design time we have given `[DOJInGovrService]` field as `varchar` datatype.
now when we are trying order by this parameter(`DOJInGovrService`) in ascending order it is not giving the desired result.
I know it is datatype problem but I can't change the datatype now as data is already entered.

```
SELECT ED.class, 
       ED.CurrentOfficePlace, 
       ED.DOB, 
       ED.DOJInCurrentOff, 
       ED.DOJInGovrService, 
       ED.DOJInSamvarg, 
       ED.EmpName, 
       ED.HomePlace, ED.Qualification 
FROM tbl_EmplyeesBiodata ED
ORDER BY DOJInGovrService asc
```

Date entered is in format `dd-MM-yyyy` (i.e. 28-08-2004).

please help me

Comment: How about adding an additional column to your table which has type `datetime2` (which will allow proper sorting by date), `UPDATE` the table to fill the new column based on the values from the existing `DOJInGovrService` column, (optionally delete the old column and change your code), and do a `ORDER BY NewDateTimeColumn`?

Comment: Of course you can change it. Create a new datetime-column(or date), then use an update statement which updates the new column with the date value, use `Convert` or `Cast` to convert it from varchar to datetime. Finally delete the old column and rename the new to the old. Change it, the earlier  the better.

Comment: Do ***NOT*** store dates in a `varchar` column. Fix your data model and you will not have any problems doing the sorting properly

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name That's true. What with situation when RDBMS doesn't provide format date that you need?

Comment: Then I would immediately dismiss that RDBMS as a serious consideration to be used in any production environment.

Comment: thanks for your replies. Creating new column and update it with the old column data is the only solution. But Update the new column with the values in old column, data will remain the same though !!!! so again it will create the problem.

Comment: thanks this query worked for me thanks..
"select ED.class,ED.CurrentOfficePlace,ED.DOB,ED.DOJInCurrentOff,ED.DOJInGovrService,ED.‌​DOJInSamvarg,ED.EmpName,ED.HomePlace,ED.Qualification from tbl_EmplyeesBiodata ED order by convert(date,DOJInGovrService,105) asc"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is just one of many reasons why you should **Always** use appropriate data types.
Even when you have data in the table, you can change the data type using an [`alter table`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190273.aspx) ddl statement:

```
ALTER TABLE tableName
ALTER COLUMN ColumnName datetime2;
```

However, you should copy this table first and try the alter on the copy, so that if it messes up your data you will not risk anything.
If the alter is successful then do it on your live table. if not, you can go with a different approach, involving these stages:

1. rename the `DOJInGovrService` column to `DOJInGovrService_old`. [use `sp_RENAME.`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16296622/rename-column-sql-server-2008)
2. Add a column `DOJInGovrService` with the correct datatype (datetime2), using `alter table` ddl stement.
3. Update the new `DOJInGovrService` column with the values in `DOJInGovrService_old`. you will probably need to use [`convert`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx).
4. drop the `DOJInGovrService_old` column using the `alter table` ddl statement.

Comment: thank you so much Zohar Peled. I think this is the only solution :)

Comment: Glad to help. However, If you find an answer that provide the correct solution to your problem you should accept it so that other people will know that the problem is solved.

Answer (score 2):

Try to convert it to datetime

```
select ED.class,ED.CurrentOfficePlace,ED.DOB,ED.DOJInCurrentOff,ED.DOJInGovrService,ED.DOJInSamvarg,ED.EmpName,ED.HomePlace,ED.Qualification 
from tbl_EmplyeesBiodata ED 
order by convert(date,DOJInGovrService,105) asc
```

This is only direct solution. The best way to do that is create new column with `date` type. The column will helps you to create query without `cast` or `convert`.

Comment: This is certainly the answer to the question as asked, but do bear in mind that when some value that isn't castable to a datetime inevitably makes its way into this field, this will stop working, and it will be a pain to track down the problem. Also, this will be slower than using a real datetime field with an index on it. Pay heed to the comments and consider taking the extra time to change the field itself to a datetime value.

Comment: thanks for your suggestion parado. I also think creating new column is the only solution, as i have tried your query it is also giving error "The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value"

Comment: @ankitsrist probably some of dates are not in correct format

Comment: This query worked for me thanks.."select ED.class,ED.CurrentOfficePlace,ED.DOB,ED.DOJInCurrentOff,ED.DOJInGovrService,ED.DOJInSamvarg,ED.EmpName,ED.HomePlace,ED.Qualification from tbl_EmplyeesBiodata ED order by convert(date,DOJInGovrService,105) asc"

Comment: @ankitsrist Thanks, for the solution, I updated my answer to make it correct.