# updating with cast(date as datetime) gives different result

Tags: sql-server

I am querying this

```
UPDATE maindb SET date  = CAST(date as DATETIME) WHERE date LIKE'%1974%'
```

so I'm expecting a result of

```
date
1974-12-12
1974-12-13
1974-12-14
```

However when I query

```
select * from maindb where date like '%1974%'
```

The result is all like this

```
May 28 1974 12:00AM
```

Why is this? I remember query something like this

```
SET *Some code i forgot* 120
```

How can I set back?
EDIT:
For the record my `date` column is in `varchar(20)` I don't know why but the company wants it to a new database/normalize and have 100k records. I learned that if **all** the data in the `date` column is set to `yyyy-mm-dd` format, you can change the column to `datetime`

Comment: You're getting this "error" because your `date` field is a character type (e.g. varchar(20)). Casting a datetime to a character type defaults to format 0 (or 100). The code you're forgetting is converting it to format 120, e.g. `SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), date, 120) FROM maindb;`. See "Date and Time Styles" on [this page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql) for information about type conversion.

Comment: Yes I know it is a varchar. but the table already have a 100k of records. So I want it to be converted to the proper one `datetime`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 issues here.

- First, what type of field is your `date` field? If it is really `datetime`, then it will normally display the date and time, as you observe.
- Second, although the `date` type is simpler than a full `datetime` type, the effective time is midnight at the beginning of the day. So, if you cast a simple `date` field to a `datetime` type, then you will get the date plus midnight.

If you really want to output the date as you list, then use `cast date as date)`. To make the intention clear, you could use `cast "date" AS date`, to make clear that the first use of `date` is the column name.

As regards setting the data back to the old values, welcome to the wonderful world of SQL, where there is no undo. SQL Server does have the ability to restore to a certain extent, but it’s not always easy.

It’s a little confusing to talk about, since `date` refers to a field type as well as the name of one of your columns.

If you want to retrofit a corrected version of the date into an existing character field, you can try:

```
UPDATE maindb SET date=cast(cast(date as date) as char);
```

Comment: the date field is in `string` sorry if i forgot to tell

Comment: @Wowie It’s not a good idea to use a string type. The `cast` should still work. What data do you have in your column, and what result did you want?

Comment: Sorry but that database is from the old company. So I am migrating it to the new and ok table

Comment: the result i dont want is this `May 28 1974 12:00AM` which is ofcourse the result of `select * from maindb` I want the proper one for the `datetime` type

Comment: Hey I tried your `UPDATE maindb SET date  =  cast(date as date)  WHERE date LIKE'%1973%'` and it worked! I don't know why but the `convert(date, datetime)` doesn't?

Comment: I don't know man but your edited answer gives the same result.

Answer (score 0):

`DATETIME` [datatype in SQL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/data-types-transact-sql) has time component added to it. So, when you cast your [datatype](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/data-types-transact-sql) to [datetime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/date-and-time-data-types-and-functions-transact-sql), it is initialized the time to 12:00 AM. To fix your issue:

1. Create a new column with date type [link to add column](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_alter.asp)
2. cast the existing column as `date` datatype into the new column `UPDATE maindb SET date  = CAST(date as DATE) WHERE date LIKE'%1974%'`
3. Drop the old column [link to drop column](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_alter.asp)
4. Rename the new column [link to rename column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16296622/rename-column-sql-server-2008)

Answer (score 0):

First add one column and store converted dates

```
 select *, convert(datetime, date) as new_date from maindb  WHERE date LIKE'%1974%'
```

Then update into main table to the respective column

```
UPDATE maindb
 SET date  = new_date
```

or

```
UPDATE maindb
 SET date  =  convert(datetime, date, 100)  WHERE date LIKE'%1974%'
```

Comment: it still displahying `May 28 1974 12:00AM`

Comment: @Wowie I Tried with first one and it is working fine

Comment: I used this `UPDATE maindb SET date=cast(cast(date as date) as char) WHERE date LIKE '%1974%';`