# Add a prefix for each column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with a lot of columns and I would like to add the prefix `ABC_` for every columns.

I tried the below query :

```
    SELECT syscolumns.name as old_column_name, 'ABC_' + syscolumns.name as new_column_name
    FROM sysobjects 
    JOIN syscolumns ON sysobjects.id = syscolumns.id
    WHERE sysobjects.name = 'ABCtable'
    ORDER BY sysobjects.name,syscolumns.colid
```

When I execute above query I got all my columns with the prefix `ABC_` but in my table nothing has changed.

Comment: You have just done a regular select statement and not told it to update anything.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Rename column SQL Server 2008](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16296622/rename-column-sql-server-2008)

Comment: Why/how is adding `ABC_` onto the start of all of the column names going to *help* you here? You'll still have the same large amount of columns and you've now worsened e.g. intellisense.

Comment: No I have to do this to realize a jointure with an other table. It is not a duplicate because in my cas I want to add a prefix for each columns not to rename one column.

Comment: Have you considered using table aliases to disambiguate column names from different tables and column aliases to uniquely label them?

Comment: No how do you do this ?

Comment: Don't do this. You will gain nothing!

Comment: Request you to up vote my answer if you found right and helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this.

```
    DECLARE @Colums AS TABLE(IndexNo INT IDENTITY(1,1), OldCol VARCHAR(MAX), NewCol VARCHAR(MAX))
    INSERT INTO @Colums
    SELECT syscolumns.name as old_column_name, 'ABC_' + syscolumns.name as new_column_name
    FROM sysobjects 
    JOIN syscolumns ON sysobjects.id = syscolumns.id
    WHERE sysobjects.name = 'ABCtable'
    ORDER BY sysobjects.name,syscolumns.colid


    DECLARE @I INT=1;
    WHILE EXISTS(SELECT * FROM @Colums WHERE IndexNo=@I)
    BEGIN
        DECLARE @OldCol VARCHAR(MAX)='', @NewCol VARCHAR(MAX)=''
        SELECT @OldCol='ABCtable.'+OldCol, @NewCol=NewCol FROM @Colums WHERE IndexNo = @I

        EXEC sp_rename @OldCol, @NewCol, 'COLUMN'

        SET @I = @I+1;
    END
```

Comment: It is exactly what I wanted ! Thank you very much !

Answer (score 0):

You can use sp_rename to rename a column/table.

```
EXEC sp_rename 'TableName.OldColumnName', 'NewColumnName', 'COLUMN'
```

Comment: Thank you but I have a lot of columns not just one :/

Comment: Just Copy and Paste the query and then rename it. You can Exec it at the Same time.

Comment: I have 10 000 columns so it is not the best idea ... :/

Comment: 10 000 columns?!? Seems like your db really needs to be redesigned.

Comment: also not possible unless using sparse columns

Answer (score 0):

You can create a cursor as shown below. Please find the below query.

```
create table studInfo (Id int, EmpCode Varchar(20), Name Varchar(20))
insert into studInfo values (1,'1001', 'A'),(2, '1002','B'), (3, '1003','C'), (4,'1004', 'D'), (5,'1005', 'E')

select * from studInfo

Declare @OldSQLcolName Varchar(50)
Declare @NewColName Varchar(50)

DECLARE RenameCursor CURSOR FOR
SELECT 'studInfo.' + COLUMN_NAME
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_NAME = N'studInfo'

OPEN RenameCursor;
FETCH NEXT FROM RenameCursor INTO @OldSQLcolName;

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
   BEGIN      
      set @NewColName = 'ABC_' + Replace(@OldSQLcolName,'studInfo.','')
      --select @OldSQLcolName, @NewColName

      EXEC sp_rename @OldSQLcolName, @NewColName, 'COLUMN'
      FETCH NEXT FROM RenameCursor INTO @OldSQLcolName;   
   END

CLOSE RenameCursor
DEALLOCATE RenameCursor

select * from studInfo
drop table studInfo
```

The output before and after updated column name is as shown below

[image]

You can find the live demo [**Live Demo Here**](https://rextester.com/XZTV8062)