# Populate column based on another column in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

What's the best way to populate column `A` with `name` in `df1` based on the common column `ID` of `df1` and `df2`?

`df1`

```
   ID   A 
   122  nan
   233  nan
       ...
```

`df2`

```
   ID   B    name 
   122  10   real_name1
   233  20   real_name2
       ...
```

to get:

```
   ID   A 
   122  real_name1
   233  real_name2
        ...
```

---

Edit:
I would also like to change the column name `A` to `new_column_name` so the expected output looks like this:

```
   ID   new_column_name
   122  real_name1
   233  real_name2
        ...
```

---

Update:

Tried:

```
UPDATE t1
SET A = t2.name
FROM df1 t1
INNER JOIN df2 t2
    ON t2.ID = t1.ID;
```

and it caught error:

```
Msg 8152, Level 16, State 2, Line 48
String or binary data would be truncated.
The statement has been terminated.
```

---

Update2:

Table definitions

`df1`:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[df1](
    [ID] [nvarchar](20) NULL,
    [SUB_ID2] [nvarchar](15) NOT NULL,
    [DATE] [datetime2](7) NULL,
    [MONTH] [nvarchar](4000) NULL,
    [QTY] [numeric](20, 8) NOT NULL,
    [SUB_ID] [nvarchar](15) NOT NULL,
    [X] [nvarchar](20) NULL,
    [SUBURB_ID] [nvarchar](30) NULL,
    [PROJECT_NAME] [nvarchar](160) NULL,
    [A] [varchar](10) NOT NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

`df2`:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[df2](
    [ID] [nvarchar](46) NULL,
    [NAME1] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [IDx] [nvarchar](15) NULL,
    [P] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [Q] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [Z] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [Y] [nvarchar](30) NULL,
    [MARK] [nvarchar](10) NULL,

) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Comment: please also tag your DBMS.

Comment: This looks a lot like Pandas.  Are you sure that you're using SQL Server here?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen yes I'm using SSMS

Comment: Edit your question and include the table definitions for both tables.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Hi please see question update2

Comment: You need to make the `A` column in the first table _wider_ to accommodate the larger width of the `NAME1` column in the second table.

Comment: @DaleK hey thanks for the advice. I tried to google but there's mixed information and I didn't want to accidentally break the system thus resorting to help from someone experienced.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you actually want to *update* the first table, then use:

```sql
UPDATE t1
SET A = t2.name
FROM df1 t1
INNER JOIN df2 t2
    ON t2.ID = t1.ID;
```

If you really wanted to express the update logic using a join, you could use an updatable CTE:

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT t1.A, t2.name
    FROM df1 t1
    INNER JOIN df2 t2 ON t2.ID = t1.ID
)

UPDATE cte
SET A = name;
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Btw do you know a safe way to change column name `A` to `new_column_name`?

Comment: @nilsinelabore Just follow [this highly viewed SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16296622/rename-column-sql-server-2008) for help on that.

Comment: Hi thanks, what does it mean `The multi-part identifier "b.name" could not be bound.`?

Answer (score 1):

It is simple join.

```
Select t1.id, t2.name as A
  From df1 t1 join df2 t2 on t1.id = t2.id
```

Even you don't need `df1` in the query. All required values are available in `df2`.

If there is a case when `df2` do not contain some id then use `left join.`

Comment: The way the OP wrote it, it sounds like they want an update rather than a 'view' of the data.

Comment: Got it @DavidBrossard