# Rename a table column that has a huge amount of data in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sqlperformance

I want to change column of table that table has more than 5 millions records.
this column related to a few indexes and I have to drop these indexes and rename column and after that recreate indexes.
this process take to much time. almost 1:30 hour.
does have better solution to rename that column with better performance?

Comment: Most of the answers to [this old SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16296622/4003419) seem to suggest [sp_rename](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-rename-transact-sql). But I have no idea about how good it is with renaming a column used in several indexes.

Comment: sp_rename will indeed handle columns used in indexes.

Comment: `sp_rename` will handle indexes and (foreign key) constraints fine. It won't affect other objects that reference the column though, such as `VIEW`s, `PROCEDURE`s, `FUNCTION`s, etc.

Comment: @Stu unfortunately not. sp_rename return error coz of indexes

Comment: What error are you getting, Mousa? Show us what you've *actually* tried. For a "simple" set up, `sp_rename` works fine: [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=039657920d4cc677cc2082e3afefffc8).

Comment: @Larnu error : Object 'dbo.tablename.column' cannot be renamed because the object participates in enforced dependencies.

Comment: Do you have calculated columns that reference the column, @MousaGhajarNajafi ? If so, you'll need to `DROP` those first and recreate them; the indexes would be handled fine.

Comment: @Larnu yes i have 2 calculated columns. DROP and recreate these columns takes too much time

Comment: Are these computed columns persisted then, @MousaGhajarNajafi ? All this informations should be in your question... The attempt(s) you made, the error(s) you get, etc, etc...

Comment: [Here's a small test](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=cead9db327c461d701000aaf95d7a4f8) tthat replicates the problem. I guess you first need to drop the computed columns that use the column. If it's not a persisted computed column that should be fast.

Comment: This is a one time change? If so, does it really matter if you can speed it up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create an empty table with the correct definition. Select old data into the table with the correct structure. DROP old table.