# Renaming the column names in batch using SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql-server, table-rename

I found this useful query to rename all my tables, indexes and constrains but I just figured out it didn't rename the columns.

```
SELECT 'exec sp_rename ' + '''' + NAME + '''' + ', ' + '''' + replace(NAME, 'Tb', 'Tabela') + ''''
FROM sysObjects
WHERE
NAME LIKE 'Tb%'
```

I know there's syscolumns but I'm not sure how to use in this case.

Question: How can I get the same result of this query but for columns instead of tables?

I appreciate your help in this. I'm using SQL Server 2012. Thanks.

Comment: I mean, you are just selecting data, which in this case should give you every query you need to actually run. You'll have to copy the results, paste them in a window and then run it

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: The question is... how I get the same result of this query but for columns instead of tables.

Comment: You mean something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/174586/5894241

Answer (score 2):

You have to do a little more work:

```
SELECT 'exec sp_rename ' + '''' + QUOTENAME(s.name) + '.' + QUOTENAME(o.name) + '.' + QUOTENAME(c.name) + '''' + ', ' + '''' + replace(c.name, 'Col', 'Column') + ''', ''COLUMN'''
FROM sys.columns c
    INNER JOIN sys.objects o ON c.object_id = o.object_id
    INNER JOIN sys.schemas s ON o.schema_id = s.schema_id
WHERE c.name LIKE 'Col%'
```

Since you are renaming column, you must specify that third argument to `sp_rename` is `COLUMN`. You must also construct three part name in the form of `[schema].[table name].[current column name]` to point to the correct column.

Comment: Worked perfectly! Thank you very much, nejcs!

Comment: I'm glad that it worked. Please approve this answer and consider upvoting it.